# Use a Poetry built module inside of another Poetry built module

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a custom general module `module_a` built with poetry and published to a Gitlab private package registry.
I wish to use this module in another more specific module `module_b`, but I cannot manage to add this dependency with the `poetry add <package name>` command.
For now I am only able to install *module_a* dependency inside the virtualenv created by Poetry on *module_b* using `poetry run pip install ... --extra-index-url ...`
What is the best practice in this use case?
Do you know how to add this dependency to the pyproject.toml file or should I always install both module `module_a` and `module_b` when I only want to use `module_b`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to achieve this.

1. The easiest one is to pass the GitHub path of the other library. This approach works both in development and production environments.

   `poetry add git+https://github.com/your-github/your-module.git`

   Poetry will automatically download, build, and install it in your current repo. You can also pinpoint your specific version by mentioning the tag or branch in the GitHub URL.

   `poetry add "git+https://github.com/your-github/your-module.git@1.2.3"`
2. The second method is to directly pass the local path of the other library in your `pyproject.toml` file. This works when you are changing both repos at the same time while testing your project.

   ```
   [tool.poetry.dependencies]
   my-dependency = {path = "../path/to/your-module", develop = true}
   ```
3. Another approach is to create a wheel file from your module, and use its path in your `pyproject.toml` file.

   ```
   [tool.poetry.dependencies]
   my-dependency = {path = "../path/to/built/your-module.whl"}
   ```

Comment: Is option 2. suppose to hot reload when code on `your-module` changes?

Comment: reloading depends on how you execute your code. but the module will be installed in place, so anytime you run your code, it will have access to the new `your-module` code.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry's dependencies are supposed to be public dependencies.  If your `module_b` is going to be public, publish it to `pypi` and add it as you normally would.  If it isn't, make `module_a` a git submodule of `module_b` in the right place, and access `module_b` that way.

Alternatively, set up a private repository, and add it to your `pyproject.toml` as such:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "foo"
url = "https://foo.bar/simple/"
```

[See the docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories#install-dependencies-from-a-private-repository) for more information.

### Private Repositories

These are private *python package repositories*, not merely git repositories.  You need a full server instance, with storage, to run a private repository, although there are services lke [this one](https://www.packagr.app/) (never used; no affiliation) who will run one for you---for a fee, of course. See the [python docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/) for more information on how package servers work.

If you go the submodule route, poetry doesn't handle the dependency at all---you just import directly from the code of `module_a`, so it needs to be cloned or symlinked into your source tree.  This is a good deal easier than setting up a whole repository, but of course you have to handle the dependency yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  
`module_a` cannot be public in my case, and `module_a` and `module_b` are in distinct repos. If I understand well I could either:

- publish `module_a` to `module_b` package repo which is already in poetry source since it is where `module_b` is published
- add both `module_a` and `module_b` in poetry sources of `module_b` since it seems we can have several of them?

Comment: see updated answer: that might clarify things.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'several of them', but you can definitely have several private repositories, and poetry will take the first match it finds.